# TASM error when trying to initialize a variable with an address

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I'm getting an error on my first TASM program. These are the 2 errors that throws:

At my .DATA

```
    LisData db 10,20,30,40,50 
    Inicio db [LisData] ;ERROR! expecting scalar type
```

and then at .CODE

```
    mov Bx, Inicio ;ERROR! operand types don't match
```

Maybe it's a very obvious mistake but I know too little of TASM and will appreciate your help

Finally this is the compete .asm file

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
Long db 5
Sumver db 0
LisData db 10,20,30,40,50
Inicio db [LisData]
.CODE
CALCULO:
  mov Ch, 0
  mov Cl, Long
  mov Bx, Inicio
  mov Al, [Bx]
  CICLO:
    add Bx, 1
    add Al, [Bx]
    loop CICLO
  mov Sumver, Al
  mov ah, 004ch
  int 21h
END
```

I want the memory address of `LisData` at `Inicio`, a pointer so I can move through the values in it (10,20,30) in order to add them and store the sum at `Sumver`.

Comment: It's unclear what you even wanted to do. Please tell what value you want to have at `Inicio`.

Comment: I want the memory address of LisData, a pointer so I can move through the values in it (10,20,30) in order to add them and store the sum at Sumver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the memory address of LisData, a pointer so I can move through
>   the values in it

Then you need a word, not a byte, and you need the address itself, such as:

```
Inicio dw LisData
```

Comment: yeah! that worked. But now the linker throws: 
Fatal: No program entry point

Comment: You are missing the entry point. Append `ends CALCULO` at the end of your code.